# Google Analytics Data API V4: Stable Version Release Date

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, release, beta

Google Analytics Data API V4: Stable Version Release Date.

Hi, I'm currently using Universal Analytics Reporting API V4 inside my Java application. It will be out-of-service in a month.

I see Data API V4 is still in Beta, with packages and classes that are specific for Beta version. E.g.:

```
com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient
```

Is there an out-of-beta release planned before the end of June?
In that case, I prefer waiting for the final version before starting porting my API; otherwise, I will start using the Beta version...

Thanks.